# Как добавить шаг в 100 единиц и надпись в кол-ва товара? WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня есть сайт. Я написал код, который добавляет «за 100 г» к цене продукта (на рисунке 2). Вот код:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wb_change_product_html' );

function wb_change_product_html( $price ) {

    $cat_arr = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'product_cat');
    //return $a[0]->name;
    $temp = 0;
    foreach ($cat_arr as $singl_cat) {
        if($singl_cat->name == 'perunit') {
            $temp = 1;
        }
    }
    if ( $temp ) {
        $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . 'per unit \' ' . $price . '</span>';

    } else {
        $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . ' per 100g \ ' . $price . '</span>';
    }
    return $price_html;

}
```

Мне нужно добавить надпись к «количеству товаров, добавленных в корзину» (на картинке пункт 1). Логика такова, что если у меня есть категория «per unit», то все остается по умолчанию. Но если категории нет, то к количеству товара добавляется надпись «price per X gram», где X - количество в граммах (минимум 100) и делается шаг в 100 граммов.

Не знаю, как это сделать, может кто помочь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это поле выводится через функцию `woocommerce_quantity_input` и можно везде изменить шаг с помощью хука `woocommerce_quantity_input_step`, так пользователю будет понятно, сколько грамм он заказал.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'my_quantity_input_step' );
function my_quantity_input_step() {
    return 100; // Step
}
```

Так же может понадобиться хук `woocommerce_quantity_input_min`, для указания минимального знаачения этого поля.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'my_quantity_input_min' );
function my_quantity_input_min() {
    return 100; // Min value
}
```

Comment: а как добавить текст и категорию?

Comment: @Samalamadoit Какой текст и какую категорию?

Comment: "Но если категории нет, то к количеству товара добавляется надпись «price per X gram», где X - количество в граммах (минимум 100) и делается шаг в 100 граммов."
Вот

Comment: global $product; $product->get_category_ids() - так можно получить айди всех категорий данного товара